# Convergence of random variables: sumXn/ sqrt(n sumXn^2)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=Var(X_1)=1$.

Show that:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k }{\sqrt{n \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k^2 }} \xrightarrow{\text{prob}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I think we need to use the strong law of large numbers applied to the sequence $\{X^2_n\}_{n\geq1}$ to get that:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X^2_k }{n} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=Var(X_1)+\mathbb{E}[X_1]^2=2 $$ and then use some relation to get the result above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just divide numerator and denominator by $n$  and apply SLLN's to the sequence ${X_i}$ and $X_i^{2}$. In fact the convergence is almost sure.

Comment: Thanks! But don't you need $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|]$ also to be finite in order to apply the SLLN's?

Comment: A random variable $X$ has finite expectation  iff $E|X| <\infty$. In Lebesgue Theory there is no distinction between integrability of $X$ and integrability of $|X|$.  @Babado

Comment: In this case even the variance is given to be finite.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the Lebesgue measure... but wrt the probability measure that's true